# How to display ° (degree sign) without Â in OpenCV's status bar?

Tags: python, opencv

I'd like to display ° (degree sign) in OpenCV's status bar:

```py
cv2.displayStatusBar(winname, '°')
```

However, it displays `Â°` instead of just `°`. I guess it is an encoding related issue, but I haven't figured out, how to encode the text correctly.

---

**requirements.txt**

```
opencv-python==4.1.0.25
```

Comment: bug reports on outdated versions will always be rejected.

Comment: Just removed the "linux" tag, which was misplaced. Please read the descriptions of tags!

Comment: When `Â` characters appear for no good reason, it’s usually because a utf-8 encoded string is interpreted as if it was iso-8859-1. (You don’t usually get the right character after it, however, but the ° character as latin-1 happens to be a suffix of its own utf-8 encoding.)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I can confirm that it is fixed in the latest version `opencv-python-4.6.0.66`. I should have checked this before asking this question. Should I delete the question?